# Como fechar uma tela(navigation) no React Native, a partir de outra

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Eu preciso saber como eu fecho as telas que eu ja abri atras. 
Tipo: Estou indo A - B - C - D   ...quando eu chegar na D, eu quero voltar pra A. Mas, se eu apertar o botao de voltar tanto no Android quanto no iOS, ele vai sair da aplicação, e não voltar D - C - B - A para depois sair. Eu estou usando o Navigation para transitar entre telas.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bom?

Se caso você está usando a biblioteca [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), para você conseguir isso, você pode gerenciar o "Back" do Android usando um *BackHandler*.

Exemplo:

```
import React from 'react';
import {..., BackHandler, ... } from 'react-native';
export default class Main extends React.Component {
// ...
  exemploDeHandler(){
  //Faça Alguma coisa;
  if (!this.onMainScreen()) {
    this.goBack();
    return true;
  }
  return false;

  // Retornar true no Handler,
  // Segundo a documentação(Link logo Abaixo do Código)
  // evita a execução do comportamento default
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.ExemploDeHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.ExemploDeHandler);
  }
// ...
}
```

Documentação: [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler)